# Compile time exception for super() call from a child's constructor

Tags: java, exception

When you call `super()` from a child class's constructor, it should throw a compile time exception when the parent does not have a no arg constructor. But since Object class has a no arg constructor, will this exception be actually thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

> if Object is the **only** superclass, there is no problem.

Since `super()` calls the constructor of the **direct** super class, the **direct** super class needs to have a no-arg constructor. Classes further up in the inheritance hierarchy are not considered.

Answer (score 5):

First, it's not an exception: it's a compile-time error. That's a different beast.

The rule says that if you call `super()` (without arguments) then the **parent** class should have a no-argument constructor. Parent here means: immediate parent, not grandparent or grand-grand-parent. That's because constructors are not inherited.

So although the class `Object`, which is always an ancestor of any other class, has a constructor without arguments, this doesn't make a difference, because the constructors from Object are only accessible to its direct subclasses; they are not accessible to subclasses of subclasses (grandchildren) and further.

Answer (score -1):

Object class is the parent class of every class. So every class has no arg constructor by default. So there won't be any compilation issues in child class unless your parent class has constructor with arg.

Comment: @Andreas Fester, I think it is not mandatory to write no arg constructor explicitly in parent class